# SQL SELECT TOP 1 1 OR SELECT COUNT(1)

Tags: sql

Which is faster?

```
select top 1 1
```

or

```
select count(1)
```

Note: if you have 100,000,000 million rows of data

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: That's different..

Comment: That's different.. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is going to be faster.  Selecting an arbitrary row with an integer is almost always going to be faster than an aggregation.  If the underlying table has at most a handful of rows, the two might have essentially the same performance.